# Best way to prevent Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where we want to prevent the update of a table for a specific scenario.

So for 95% of the updates I would want the update to flow through as normal and update the desired fields....for that other 5% I want to prevent the update from happening.  This will be based on data passed in the update along with what is currently populated in the table.

So a good example is a user submitted their time for today.  If they resubmit their time I don't want the DB to allow that update to occur because the time table for that user has it flagged that they already submitted their time and the time field is NOT NULL.

I was playing with triggers for this and it appears the INSTEAD OF trigger would allow me to handle this...basically only let the update occur if that criteria holds true.

Any thoughts? I appreciate any ideas.

(Let me know if this is clear)

**EDIT:** I apologize...that was probably not a good example. We reuse an update sproc to perform many different updates so it is fairly generic.  I wanted to figureout what the best approach is for those cases where I don't want the update to be performed.  Using a trigger was basically a safeguard to prevent someone from accidentally overwriting previously entered data.  Thanks for the input

**EDIT2:**Thanks All...after thinking through it Martin is right I should just build the logic into the sproc.  I was told that they wanted to use a trigger to handle this, but you are all correct...that is just not the right way to handle this.  Thanks again for your help.

Thanks,

S

Comment: So, I couldn't correct my time if I mistakenly typed "16" instead of "8"?

Comment: This sort of logic really belongs in your application layer, not on the db.  If you insist on the db approach creating a sp to encapsulate the logic as kekekala suggests and using an intelligently written update statement as Martin Smith suggests would be a good solution.

Comment: Your edit hasn't made things that much clearer to be honest. What do you mean by "reuse an update sproc"? You have 1 generic procedure that updates different tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for this. e.g. something like

```
UPDATE Users 
 SET timefield = @timefield
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND [Day]=@day AND timefield IS NULL
```

Would work for your example. You could then check the rows affected to see whether anything was actually updated or not.

Comment: Right - just build your business rules into either a non-database abstraction layer, or this SQL syntax is fine, especially if it's in an SP (another useful place for business rules); just don't get into triggers.